# Running a background process on Windows 7/XP

Tags: python, windows-7, windows-xp, background-process

I am in the process of developing an application using python that needs to be able to run on both Windows 7 and XP. The application takes some simple inputs from buttons on the UI and based on the selections it needs to modify some numbers and then either upload them to a website or add them to a queue to be uploaded later.

My problem is that i need the process which modifies the numbers and does the uploading to run in the background. I am inexperienced at programming so I'm not sure how exactly to do it. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Edit: Sorry I don't think I was exactly clear. It is making something run in the background that I am having trouble doing. Specifically I need the background process to run until a command is given for it to stop. It is working with a steady stream of input numbers that it is modifying and then uploading one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the use on both operating systems I suggest using `py2exe`. Even my Python 2.7 64bit compiled scripts work on Windows XP machines, so I guess this should work.

How would you wish to upload these numbers to the homepage, via a GET form or via FTP, GET should be easier. 
Assuming, your file is at `http://example.com/testfile.php`, you would just open this file with urllib:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen("http://example.com/testfile.php?number1=20&number2=100")
```

If you want to upload the numbers via FTP, I suggest using `ftplib`, a standard ftp-library built in Python.

EDIT: Forgot to mention to run it in a separate thread:

```
import thread
thread.start_new_thread(upload_function()) #using the upload-process in a new function
```

Comment: I was looking at threading and I actually think it will work just fine. All I had to do was read a little and adjust how I was thinking I needed to do things. Thanks :)